# Login Form text boxes won't disappear

Tags: html, css, angular

I've created this simple Login form for a uni project and for some reason the box around the text field is still showing, I want it to be invisible.
How the form works is; when a user clicks on either field, the placeholder lifts up and they type below it (refer to screenshot)
For some reason, however, the text box is still there.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.center {
      position:fixed;
      top: 40%;
      left: 70%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 720px;
      height: 350px;
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, white, silver );
      size: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      border-width: 1px;
    
    }
    
    .center h1{
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0 0 20px 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    }
    
    .center form {
        padding: 0 40px;
    }
    
    form .txt_field {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
    margin: 30px 0;
    }
    
    .txt-field input {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0 5px;
     height: 40px;
     font-size: 16px;
     border: none;
     background: none;
     outline: none;
    }
    
   
    
    .no-outlin:focus{
      outline: none;
    }
    
    .txt_field label{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 5px;
      color: #adadad;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      font-size: 16px;
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: .7s;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .txt_field span::before{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0%;
      height: 2px;
      background: #2691d9;
      transition: .7s;
    }
    
    .txt_field input:focus ~ label,
    .txt_field input:valid ~ label {
      top: -5px;
      color: #2691d9;
    }
    
    .txt_field input:focus ~ span::before,
    .txt_field input:valid ~ span::before {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .pass {
      margin: -5px 0 20px 5px;
      color: #a6a6a6;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .pass:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    input[type="submit"]{
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid;
      background: #2691d9;
      border-radius: 25px;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #e9f4fb;
      font-weight: 700;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
    }
    
    input[type="submit"]:hover{
      border-color: #2691d9;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .signup_link {
      margin: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #666666;
    }
    
    .signup_link a{
      color: #2691d9;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .signup_link a:hover{
      color: #2691d9;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    
    </head>
    <body class="Body">
    
      <div class="center">
        <h1> Login </h1>
        <form method="post" class="Box">
         <div class="txt_field">
           <input  type="text" required>
           <span></span>
           <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="txt_field">
        <input type="password" required>
        <span></span>
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="pass"> Forgotten Password? </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <div class="signup_link">
      Not a Member? <a class="nav-item-nav-link" routerLink="/register">Create an Account!</a>
    </div>
    
    </form>
    </div>
```

[Click here for sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIt6N.jpg)

Comment: There's a typo in your css code. It should be "txt_field", not "txt-field".

Comment: Thank you for that, it's working how i wanted now. Greatly appreciated! @Debsmita Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your CSS

Change the `txt-field` in your CSS to `txt_field`

This is your code:

```css
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 720px;
  height: 350px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, white, silver);
  size: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.center h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.center form {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

form .txt_field {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.txt_field input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.no-outlin:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.txt_field label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  color: #adadad;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .7s;
  border: none;
}

.txt_field span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #2691d9;
  transition: .7s;
}

.txt_field input:focus~label,
.txt_field input:valid~label {
  top: -5px;
  color: #2691d9;
}

.txt_field input:focus~span::before,
.txt_field input:valid~span::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.pass {
  margin: -5px 0 20px 5px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pass:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #2691d9;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e9f4fb;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  border-color: #2691d9;
  transition: .5s;
}

.signup_link {
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666666;
}

.signup_link a {
  color: #2691d9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.signup_link a:hover {
  color: #2691d9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body class="Body">

  <div class="center">
    <h1> Login </h1>
    <form method="post" class="Box">
      <div class="txt_field">
        <input type="text" required>
        <span></span>
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="txt_field">
        <input type="password" required>
        <span></span>
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="pass"> Forgotten Password? </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
      <div class="signup_link">
        Not a Member? <a class="nav-item-nav-link" routerLink="/register">Create an Account!</a>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It is working now

Answer (score 0):

target the input not thee div

```css
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 720px;
  height: 350px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, white, silver);
  size: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.center h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.center form {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

form .txt_field {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.txt_field input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.no-outlin:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.txt_field label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  color: #adadad;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .7s;
  border: none;
}

.txt_field span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #2691d9;
  transition: .7s;
}

.txt_field input:focus~label,
.txt_field input:valid~label {
  top: -5px;
  color: #2691d9;
}

.txt_field input:focus~span::before,
.txt_field input:valid~span::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.pass {
  margin: -5px 0 20px 5px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pass:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #2691d9;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e9f4fb;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  border-color: #2691d9;
  transition: .5s;
}

.signup_link {
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666666;
}

.signup_link a {
  color: #2691d9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.signup_link a:hover {
  color: #2691d9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body class="Body">

  <div class="center">
    <h1> Login </h1>
    <form method="post" class="Box">
      <div class="txt_field">
        <input type="text" required>
        <span></span>
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="txt_field">
        <input type="password" required>
        <span></span>
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="pass"> Forgotten Password? </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
      <div class="signup_link">
        Not a Member? <a class="nav-item-nav-link" routerLink="/register">Create an Account!</a>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```